# Windows cannot read SD card, gives 'Please insert SD card into drive E:' error

Tags: windows-10, micro-sd-card

When I try to open/format/diskpart clean the drive it cannot do the task.  All my other devices work just fine, including my Switch, camera, and tablet, can format/save files/read data but my Windows 10 machine refuses.  Other MicroSD cards using the same adapter show up fine, trying to read the SD card through the camera does not work, nor does using a different adapter fix the problem.  Nothing I try can fix the problem, and I can't seem to find a thread on here with answers.  Any help?

Comment: Does it just not appear? Does it appear when connected to any other machines?

Comment: Boot that Windows PC with a Linux LiveUSB for test and see if you can read it then; if so, it's a hardware issue. Download Ubuntu's ISO file at https://ubuntu.com/download then check for download errors per https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on your Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows then reboot and from your boot manager, choose the LiveUSB. Can you see the MicroSD card then?

Comment: If you have a Mac and the SD is FAT, FAT32, or ExFat, then you can run First Aid in Disk Utility. Also, make sure the fs is readable by Windows 10

Comment: @NasirRiley it appears, but when trying to access the card it pops the error up.

Answer (score 0):

Could be this card is a skosh out of alignment to the left, and the socket on the Windows 10 PC you tested it with is a smidgen out of alignment to the right... which would explain why all you other devices can use it.

Comment: So would it be just an issue where I need to push the card one way or another to get it to contact right?